# Background not changing color

Tags: java, swing, paint, java-2d, contentpane

So I'm trying to change the background on a full screen game I'm making from a tutorial, I'm trying to change the background to green, but it stays black, what's wrong with the code?

Screen.java

```
package debels;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Screen {
    private GraphicsDevice vc;

    public Screen(){
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    }

    public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window){
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);

        if (dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
            try{
                vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
            }catch (Exception e){}
        }
    }

    public Window getFullScreen(){
        return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    }

    public void restoreScreen(){
        Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
        if (w != null){
            w.dispose();
        }
        vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package debels;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7498470134154894036L;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run(dm);
    }

    public void run(DisplayMode dm){
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));

        Screen s = new Screen();
        try{
            s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
            try{
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }finally{
            s.restoreScreen();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Hello",  200, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start by saying, I don't think the `Thread.sleep` is doing you any favours, nor is the `paint` method.

Comment: The Thread.sleep is just to see the fullscreen, the paint method doesn't seem to conflict, since it works as expected

Comment: *"paint method doesn't seem to conflict, since it works as expected"* - That's the problem, it isn't working as it should, see my answer for more details ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first problem is going to be your `paint` method...

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("Hello",  200, 200);
}
```

Part of the responsibility of the `paint` method is to paint...the background.  But since you're not calling `super.paint` this can't happen.

You should avoid overriding `paint` on top level containers, like `JFrame` and instead use a custom component, like `JPanel` for example, and override their `paintComponent` method (not forgetting to call `super.paintComponent`).

Another area of potential issue is the use of `Thread.sleep`, this could be causing the Event Dispatching Thread to be halted, preventing from processing new paint requests.  A better solution might be to use a `javax.swing.Timer`, which will pause in the background and provide notification (via a `ActionListener`) within the context of the EDT...

**For example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestFullScreen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFullScreen();
    }

    public TestFullScreen() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());

                final Screen s = new Screen();
                DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
                s.setFullScreen(dm, frame);

                Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        s.restoreScreen();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            String text = "It's not easy to be green";
            int x = (width - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
            int y = ((height - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
            System.out.println(width + "x" + height);
            System.out.println(x + "x" + y);
            g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

    public class Screen {

        private GraphicsDevice vc;

        public Screen() {
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        }

        public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window) {
            window.setUndecorated(true);
            window.setResizable(false);
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);

            if (dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
                try {
                    vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }

        public Window getFullScreen() {
            return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
        }

        public void restoreScreen() {
            Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
            if (w != null) {
                w.dispose();
            }
            vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite confused at the moment, I'm quite new to the graphical part on Java, how would I go with writing a string on the screen or an image without replacing paint?

Comment: You're on the right track. But what you've done is replaced all the work that `paint` was doing with your text drawing...

Comment: I tried changing the background, foreground and font change to the paint method, but it doesn't seem to do much difference, I still get the black screen :/

Comment: Check my example.  You need to allow the `paint` method to do it's job and THEN add your extra work on top...

Comment: Well I just changed from JFrame to JPanel and added the JPanel to the JFrame and it worked.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to overcome the challenge. I removed the setBackground, setForeground, and setFont from the run method in the Main class and added them to the setFullScreen method in the Screen class:

```
    window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
    window.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    window.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
```

Thereafter, I added "super.paint(g);" as the first line of the paint method in the Main class

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make 3 little changes and it will work. Follow these steps:

Step-1:Add getContentPane() to setBackgroud() which is present in the run() method

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
```

Step-2: Cut & paste below lines from run() method to paint() method.

```
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
setForeground(Color.BLUE);
setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
```

step-3: Add super.paint(g) in the starting of paint() method. the whole paint() method will look like this;

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        g.drawString("Hello",  200, 200);
       }
```

if it still doesn't work let me know in the comment! #YNWA